# image gallery darken button

Tags: javascript, html, css

in the top right of my image gallery, there is a button that when clicked creates an overlay that darken the image. I want to be able to toggle it on and off when i click it. How can i achieve this?

This is my code

https://codepen.io/Modestas/pen/qPypXZ?editors=1010

```
btn.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
 var btnClass = btn.getAttribute("class");
  if(btnClass === "dark") {
    overlay.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)";
    btn.textContent = "Lighten";
    btn.setAttribute("class", "light"); 
  } else if (btn.className != "dark") {
    overlay.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
    btn.textContent = "Darken";
    btn.setAttribute("class", "dark"); 
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `overlay.backgroundColor =` do `overlay.style.backgroundColor =`